# Do states of two particles contain almost all information of their observable universe?

Tags: information, observable-universe

I am asking the question as a layman. If things are interacting with every other things in their observable universe, and if one knows the particular states, for example, the electromagnetic force, gravity force etc two particles are experiencing in almost all the directions, can one infer where all the other particles and types of particles etc are from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to think about it.  Suppose the two particles are free electrons ("free" meaning not attached to anything and not confined). All the forces together on an electron cause it to accelerate in some direction.  That acceleration requires only three numbers for its full description.  So, the two electrons taken together only can convey six numbers to describe the forces they experience.

The two electrons can only contain enough information to allow inference of six numbers to describe the experience from the vast number of other particles in the universe.  To actually describe where all the other particles are, you would need at least 3 numbers for each of those particles: a gigantic number.  In fact, you would also need to know the velocities and orientations of all the other particles, so you would need roughly (3 + 3 + 2) times the number of particles.

It's of course more complicated than the above argument suggests, but the conclusion is correct.  The bottom line reason is that the electrons will only experience forces equal to the sum of the forces due to other particles, and the individual forces are not resolvable by the two electrond; nor can the individual forces be determined by measurement of the electrons' states or motion.

Comment: Sounds like say there are x numbers of particles which are all still and there's only one kind of force, then measuring the acceleration and position of a particle which could move x times could give the positions of all the other x particles.

Comment: Not sure I understand-- "move x times?"